# Failed to create parent directory when I start a new project?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I tried each and everything possible like updating my Android Studio, enable gradle in offline mode, in fact I reinstalled Android Studio two times at different location but nothing is working, every time getting the same error:

> Error:Failed to create parent directory        'C:\Users\professional.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google\google\1'   when creating directory 'C:\Users\professional.gradle\caches\modules-2\files- 2.1\com.google\google\1\c35a5268151b7a1bbb77f7ee94a950f00e32db61'

Comment: after some research...it seems gradle build is failed while creating cache due to some existing file....but still dont know how to resolve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is solved after deleting the *complete* activity file and XML file in it, creating a new activity and then just cleaning and rebuilding your project will resolve the error and run the app.

Comment: is there another way?